# How to bind IsEnabled property to a more dynamic property in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `TabItem` that has its `IsEnabled` property bound to a ViewModel property called `IsSaved`.

It looks like this:

```
<TabItem Header="POs"
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaved, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Beautiful, right? In my `ViewModel` the property `IsSaved` is not quite as simple. It is defined as:

```
public bool IsSaved
{
    get
    {
        return IsDeveloper 
                   && CheckValidation(null) 
                   && !IsDirty 
                   && !displayMasterRepository.IsObjectChanged(); //TODO: this does not work.
    }
}
```

Now obviously this will never update the View because there is on `OnPropertyChanged` event happening here. In fact, if I knew where to put the `OnPropertyChanged` I would, but in this instance many, many things can trigger a change of this property so that doesn't make sense. What would someone do in this situation?

If this was a button with a command binding, for example, I would pass `IsSaved` into the delegate command as a CanExecute parameter and it would work dynamically. Is there something like that for a situation like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call OnPropertyChanged from any where in your code in the scope of your class.

```
     OnPropertyChanged("IsSaved");
```

Additionally i like to expose a public function for other classes to raise my property change , Something like :

```
     public void RefreshIsSaved()
     {
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSaved");  
     }
```

Or something a little less specific like :

```
     public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);     
     }
```

Is this what your asking ?

As a side note you can also write the property in a clearer manner:

```
      public bool IsSaved
      {
          get
           {
                if(IsDirty || displayMasterRepository.IsObjectChanged())
                     return false;

                return IsDeveloper && CheckValidation(null);
            }
      }
```

This will be much easier to maintain if more complex conditions would be added to your property , and it's much more readable .